# proxy server user authentication

Tags: password-reset

I have installed squid proxy server and now I try to find how to change password for any accounts via web. I search google and find chpasswd.cgi has this feature. I download the chpasswd-cgi.tar.gz and extract it :

```
tar zxf chpasswd-cgi.tar.gz
```

then, I read the README to find out how to install it. It says that just type ./configure, Then I try to enter make, then make install.

Getting below error

```
[root@proxy chpasswd-1.9.1]# make
gcc -c  -O2 -w  -I.  -DHAVE_LIBCRYPT=1 -DHAVE_DIRENT_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_CRYPT_H=1 -DHAVE_PWD_H=1 -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_STRSTR=1  -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local/etc/chpasswd\"  -DEnglish chpasswd.c
chpasswd.c:686: error: static declaration of ‘strip_latin’ follows non-static declaration
chpasswd.c:602: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘strip_latin’ was here
make: *** [chpasswd.o] Error 1


[root@proxy chpasswd-1.9.1]# make install
gcc -c  -O2 -w  -I.  -DHAVE_LIBCRYPT=1 -DHAVE_DIRENT_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_CRYPT_H=1 -DHAVE_PWD_H=1 -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_STRSTR=1  -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local/etc/chpasswd\"  -DEnglish chpasswd.c
chpasswd.c:686: error: static declaration of ‘strip_latin’ follows non-static declaration
chpasswd.c:602: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘strip_latin’ was here
make: *** [chpasswd.o] Error 1
```

How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful:  http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/200502/0464.html

However, for a function like updating passwords, I'd want to know that the security of this script is being looked after, so if it needs working over the source code just to get it to compile, I'd worry about whether it's being maintained.  I'd either look for a properly maintained distribution, or make sure I'm confident that I can maintain it myself, and have sufficiently good reasons to want to take that on.

The password file is in htpasswd format (from Apache), so there will be other software available to update the passwords.  Also squid can talk to other authentication back ends.  (eg ldap is often appropriate for the sort of environments where you want to authenticate use of squid).  Or perhaps chpasswd-cgi is available in a maintained package for your OS distribution?

You might get more helpful answers if you identify the OS distribution you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the statics word of strip latin, keep going down and you'll eventually find it.

But I having a problem.

Can we edit how many digits a password can have? I can't see to edit this part and, I'm doind a new server, and when I import the passwd_file, people with more than 8 digits, won't be able to login, because -d will limit it to 8.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to ask a new question as part of your answer - how will people find it to answer it? If you have new questions to ask, far better to ask them as new questions.